# Listagem não completa todas as linhas

Tags: php, mysql, apache

Estou com um problema na hora de realizar uma listagem.
Tem horas que lista normal e tem horas que não mostra todas as linhas

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nessa imagem acima  mostra 7 linhas mais teria que mostrar 15.
o problema é que se eu atualizar a pagina tem horas que carrega normal e tem horas que aparece só 3 linhas

não sei se existe algo relacionado a memoria do servidor ou algo parecido
oque pode ser isso?

abaixo coloco o meu código

```html
<?php 
include"../assets/verifica.php";
include"../assets/config.php";

$nivelnasessao = $_SESSION["nivel"];
if (in_array("$nivelnasessao", $nivel_aceito_adm)) { // Pega os niveis aceitos no config.php essa variavel esta la 


$id_transfer = $_SESSION["id_transfer"];
$id_prod = $_GET["id"];
$cat = $_GET["cat"];
//$nome_get = $_GET["nome"];
$id_cliente = $_GET["id_cliente"];


if ($cat == 's'){
    $voltar = 'produto_servico.php';
}elseif ($cat == 'e'){
    $voltar = 'produto_eventos.php';
}elseif ($cat == 't'){
    $voltar = 'produtos.php';
}





if (empty($_GET['id_cliente'])) {
$regra = "";
}else{
$regra = "AND reservado_a = '$id_cliente'";
}

$sql = "SELECT nome FROM produtos Where id_transfer = '$id_transfer' and id_produtos = '$id_prod'  ";
$resultado = mysql_query($sql) or die( mysql_error());
while ($row_solicitacoes = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {

$nomeprod = $row_solicitacoes['nome'];

}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if !IE]><!--><html class="fluid top-full sticky-top"><!-- <![endif]-->
<head><title><?echo $title?></title>
<?php
    function codificacao($string) {
        return mb_detect_encoding($string.'x', 'UTF-8, ISO-8859-1');
    }
?>

 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
 <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
 <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE" />
 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/admin/module.admin.page.tables.min.css" />
  <script src="../assets/components/library/modernizr/modernizr.js?v=v2.1.0"></script>

<style>
/*//////////////////////////////Auto Complete///////////////////////////////////////////////*/
 .tt-hint,.country,.city,.clientes  {
  border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-radius: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
    font-size: 18px;
    height: 28px;
    line-height: 30px;
    outline: medium none;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    width: 100%;
}

.tt-dropdown-menu {
    text-align: left;
  width: 300px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #111;
  background-color: #F1F1F1;
}
/*//////////////////////////////Trocar Imagem Radio///////////////////////////////////////////////*/
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../files/includes/auto_compl/js/jquery.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../files/includes/auto_compl/js/bootstrap.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../files/includes/auto_compl/js/typeahead.js"></script> 



<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
$('input.clientes').typeahead({
  name: 'clientes',
  remote : '../files/includes/auto_compl/clientes.php?query=%QUERY'
});
})



function validarForm1() { 
var nome = document.form1.nome.value; 
var idade = document.form1.idade.value; 
if ((nome == null) || (nome == '')){ 
alert('O campo nome é obrigatório!'); 
} 
if ((idade == null) || (idade == '')){ 
alert('O campo idade é obrigatório!'); 
} 
} 

function validarForm2() { 
var nome = document.form2.nome.value; 
var idade = document.form2.idade.value; 
if ((nome == null) || (nome == '')){ 
alert('O campo nome é obrigatório!'); 
} 
if ((idade == null) || (idade == '')){ 
alert('O campo idade é obrigatório!'); 
} 
} 


function validarForm3() { 
var nome = document.form3.nome.value; 
var idade = document.form3.idade.value; 
if ((nome == null) || (nome == '')){ 
alert('O campo nome é obrigatório!'); 
} 
if ((idade == null) || (idade == '')){ 
alert('O campo idade é obrigatório!'); 
} 
} 
</script> 


</head>
<body class="">
<div class="container-fluid fluid menu-left">
<div id="wrapper">
<!-- Menu -->
<?
include"menu_n.php";
?><br /><br /><br />

<div class="innerAll">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="widget widget-heading-simple widget-body-white">

<?php
$sql = "SELECT id,nome_fan FROM fornecedores Where id_transfer = '$id_transfer'  AND master = 'master' ";
$resultado = mysql_query($sql) or die( mysql_error());
while ($row_solicitacoes = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
 $id_for = $row_solicitacoes['id'];
$nome_fan = $row_solicitacoes['nome_fan']; 
}
?>

<div class="row">
<form id="form3" action="produto_tarifario_cad_edit_master.php" method="get" name="">
<div class="col-md-6">
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<h4><?echo $nomeprod?></h4>
</div>
<div class="col-md-5" style="text-align: right;">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?echo $id_prod?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="cat" value="<?echo $cat?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="nome" value="<?echo $nomeprod?>" />
<input type="text" name="id_cliente" autocomplete="false" value="" class="clientes" placeholder="Cliente"  />

</div>
<div class="col-md-1" style="text-align: left;">
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="submit" name="" class="btn btn-block btn-default" value="Filtrar" />
</td>
<td>
<a href="<?echo $voltar?>" class="btn btn-block btn-danger ">Voltar</a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</form>

</div>


<form id="form1" action="acao.php" method="POST">    

<?php
$nomep = $_GET['nome'];           
$cat33 = $_GET['cat'];           
?>

<input type="hidden" name="acao" value="add_tar_master" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="tipo" value="<?echo $cat33?>" />       
<input type="hidden" name="nomeprod" value="<?echo $nomep?>" />       
<input type="hidden" name="id_transfer" value="<?php echo $id_transfer?>" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="id_prod" value="<?php echo $id_prod?>" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="for" value="<?php echo $id_for?>" />       

 

<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
$(window).load(function(){
$(function () {
    var divContent = $('#formulario');
    var botaoAdicionar = $('a[data-id="1"]');
    var i = 1;

    //Ao clicar em adicionar ele cria uma linha com novos campos
    $(botaoAdicionar).click(function () {
        $('<div class="conteudoIndividual"><table cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%;">'+
'<tr>'+
<?php if($cat <> 's'){?>

'<td style="width: 200px;">Fornecedores: <select class="form-control" name="forne[]" >'+
'<option value="null">Todos</option>'+
<?php
$sql = "SELECT id,nome_fan FROM fornecedores Where id_transfer = '$id_transfer' order by nome_fan";
$resultado = mysql_query($sql) or die( mysql_error());
while ($row_solicitacoes = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
 $id_for = $row_solicitacoes['id'];
$nome_fan = $row_solicitacoes['nome_fan']; 
?>

'<option value="<?echo $id_for?>"><?echo $id_for?><?echo $nome_fan?></option>'+
<?}?>
'</select></td>'+


'<td style="width: 300px;">Tarifa Negociada: <select class="form-control" name="reservado[]" >'+
'<option value="null">Todos</option>'+
<?php
$sql = " 
SELECT e.id_empresa, e.logo ,e.nome_fan FROM acessos AS a

           LEFT JOIN empresas AS e
           ON a.id_empresa = e.id_empresa
           where  a.id_transfer = '$id_transfer' 



UNION
          SELECT id_viajantes,logo,nome    FROM viajantes Where id_transfer = '$id_transfer' order by nome_fan";
$resultado = mysql_query($sql) or die( mysql_error());
while ($row_solicitacoes = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
 $id_empresa = $row_solicitacoes['id_empresa'];
$nome_fan = $row_solicitacoes['nome_fan']; 
?>

'<option value="<?echo $id_empresa?>"><?echo $nome_fan?></option>'+
<?}?>
'</select></td>'+


'<td style="width: 150px;">Ve&iacute;culo: <select class="form-control" name="vei[]>'+
'<option value=""></option>'+
'<option value="">Outros</option>'+
'<option value="Sedan">Sedan</option>'+
'<option value="Van">Van</option>'+
'<option value="Suv">Suv</option>'+
'<option value="Mini-Van">Mini-Van</option>'+
'<option value="Micro-Onibus">Micro-Onibus</option>'+
'<option value="Onibus">Onibus</option>'+
'</select></td>'+
'<td style="width: 150px;">Extra: <select class="form-control" name="extra[]" >'+
'<option value="Normal">Normal</option>'+
'<option value="Blindado">Blindado</option>'+
'<option value="Adaptado">Adaptado</option>'+
'</select></td>'+
<?php }else{echo"";}?>



'<td>Validade Inicial:<input type="date" class="form-control"  name="ini[]" value="2018-01-01"  /></td>'+
'<td>Validade Final:<input type="date" class="form-control"  name="venc[]"  value="2018-12-31"/></td>'+
'<td><input type="checkbox" name="jump[]" value="1" /></td>'+
'<td style="width: 80px;">Moeda&nbsp;<select name="moeda[]" class="form-control">'+
'<option value="Reais">R$</option>'+
'<option value="Dolares">US$</option>'+
'<option value="Euros">€</option>'+
'</select></td><td style="width: 150px;">Valor:<input type="text" class="form-control" name="valor[]"  placeholder="Valor" /></td>'+




'<td><br><a href="#" class="linkRemover">   <span class="label label-danger"> X </span></a></td>'+
'</tr>'+




'</table>'+
'</div>').appendTo(divContent);
        $('#removehidden').remove();
        i++;
        $('<input type="hidden" name="quantidadeCampos" value="' + i + '" id="removehidden">').appendTo(divContent);
    });

    //Cliquando em remover a linha é eliminada
    $('#formulario').on('click', '.linkRemover', function () {
        $(this).parents('.conteudoIndividual').remove();
        i--;
    });
});
});//]]> 

</script>

<a href="#" data-id="1" style="text-align: left;" id="adicionarCampo"><span class="label label-success"> + Adicionar Tarifário</span></a>
   <br />
<div id="formulario"></div>
            
            <br />

<input type="submit" name="tar" value="Gravar" class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-icon glyphicons home" style="width: 50%;" />            
</form>


<hr />
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<?php
$nomep = $_GET['nome'];           
$cat33 = $_GET['cat'];           
?>
<form id="form2"  name="teste" action="acao.php?form=edit_tar_master" method="post" >   
                     <input type="hidden" name="for" value="<?php echo $id_for?>" />
                     <input type="hidden" name="nomeprod" value="<?php echo $nomep?>" />
                     <input type="hidden" name="id_prod" value="<?php echo $id_prod?>" />
                     <input type="hidden" name="tipo" value="<?echo $cat33?>" /> 
                     <input type="hidden" name="id_cliente" value="<?echo $id_cliente?>" />
                     
<table  class="table table-bordered table-primary"   ">
<tr>
<td>Cod</td>
<td>Forne</td>
<td style="width: 17%;" >Tarifa Negociada</td>
<?php
if($cat <> 's'){?>
<td style="width: 8%;">Veiculo</td>
<?}else{?>

<?}?>
<td>Extra</td>
<td>Valor</td>
<td>Validade  ( Inicio e Fim )</td>
<td>Jump</td>
<td>Site</td>
<td>Promo</td>
<td>Del</td>
</tr>  



<?
 $sql = "SELECT  
            e.nome_fan,
            id_produtos2,
            fornecedor,
            vei,
            valor,
            inicio,
            extra,
            validade,
            reservado_a,
            padrao,
            site_promocao
            moeda,
            id_empresa,
            
           
            jump,
            
           f.logo AS logof, t.site AS sitet FROM produtos_tarifario AS t
           
           LEFT JOIN fornecedores AS f
           ON f.id = t.fornecedor
           
           LEFT JOIN empresas AS e
           ON e.id_empresa = t.reservado_a
           
          
           
           
           where  t.id_produto = '$id_prod' $regra  ORDER by e.nome_fan ASC         
           ";



$resultado = mysql_query($sql) or die( mysql_error());
while ($linha3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
           
$nome_fan = $linha3['nome_fan'];           
$cod = $linha3['id_produtos2'];
$for = $linha3['fornecedor'];
$vei = $linha3['vei'];
$valor = $linha3['valor'];
$inicio = $linha3['inicio'];
$extra = $linha3['extra'];
$validade = $linha3['validade'];
$reservado = $linha3['reservado_a'];
$padrao = $linha3['padrao'];
$site = $linha3['sitet'];
if($site == 0){
$checked2 = '';  
}else{
$checked2 = 'checked';  
}

$site_promocao = $linha3['site_promocao'];
if($site_promocao == 'sim'){
$checked3 = 'checked';  
}else{
$checked3 = '';  
}
$moeda = $linha3['moeda']; 

if($moeda == 'Reais')
$sifra = 'R$';
elseif($moeda == 'Dolares')
$sifra = '$';
elseif($moeda == 'Euros'){
$sifra == '€'    ;
}

$logof = $linha3['logof'];
 if ($logof == ''){
$foto = "Todos";
}else{
$foto = "<img src=\"img/fotos/$logof\" style=\"width: 30px;\" />";    
}
 
$id_empresa2 = $linha3['id_empresa'];
$id_viajantes = $linha3['id_viajantes'];
$nome_fan2 = $linha3['nome_fan']; 
$nomev = $linha3['nome']; 

echo $jump = $linha3['jump']; 

if($jump == 1){
    $checkedjump ='checked=""';
}else{
    $checkedjump = '';
}

if($padrao == 1){
    $checked ='checked=""';
}else{
    $checked = '';
}

?>

<tr>
<td><?php echo $cod?><input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $cod?>" /></td>
<td><?php echo $foto?>  </td>      

<td> 
<select name="empresa[]" style="width: 80%;">
<option value="<?echo $id_empresa2.$id_viajantes?>"><?echo$nome_fan2.$nomev?></option>
<option value="null">Todos</option>

<?php

$sql3 = " 
SELECT e.id_empresa, e.logo ,e.nome_fan FROM acessos AS a

           LEFT JOIN empresas AS e
           ON a.id_empresa = e.id_empresa
           where  a.id_transfer = '$id_transfer'  order by nome_fan";
$resultado3 = mysql_query($sql3) or die( mysql_error());
while ($row_solicitacoes = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado3)) {
$id_empresa = $row_solicitacoes['id_empresa'];
$id_viajantes = $row_solicitacoes['id_viajantes'];
$nome_fan = $row_solicitacoes['nome_fan']; 

echo "<option value='$id_empresa'> $nome_fan</option>";
}?>
</select> 
</td>


<?php
if($cat <> 's'){
?>
<td>   <input type="text" name="vei[]" size="10"  value="<?php echo $vei?>" readonly /></td>
<?}else{
    
}?>
<td><select name="extra[]">
<option value="<?php echo $extra?>"><?php echo $extra?></option>
<option value="Normal">Normal</option>
<option value="Blindado">Blindado</option>
<option value="Adaptado">Adaptado</option>
</select></td>
<td>   
<select name="moeda[]">
<option value="<?php echo $moeda?>"><?php echo $sifra?></option>
<option value="Reais">R$</option>
<option value="Dolares">$</option>
<option value="Euros">€</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="valor[]" size="5" value="<?php echo $valor?>" /></td>
<td>   <input type="date" name="inicio[]" value="<?php echo $inicio?>" />
       <input type="date" name="fim[]" value="<?php echo $validade?>" />
</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="jump[]" <?php echo $checkedjump?> value="1" /></td>


<td>
<select name="site[]">
<option value="<?php echo $site?>"><?php echo $site?></option>
<option value="sim">Sim</option>
<option value="nao">Não</option>
</select>
</td>

<td>
<select name="site_promocao[]">
<option value="<?php echo $site_promocao?>"><?php echo $site_promocao?></option>
<option value="sim">Sim</option>
<option value="nao">Não</option>
</select>
<td>
<a href="acao.php?acao=del_tar&id_tar=<?php echo $cod?>&id=<?echo $id_prod?>&cat=<?echo $cat?>&nome=<?echo $nomeprod?>"><img src="img/del.png" width="20px" /> </a>
</td>
</tr>  
<?
}
?>


</table>
<input type="submit" name="tar" value="Editar Valores" class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-icon glyphicons home" style="width: 50%;" />              
</form>
</div>
</div>
 

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>

 

 
<?php
      }else{
  echo $erro_nivel;
}     
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Por favor, evite utilizar o snippet do site para código PHP. Quando você cria um snippet, verá que só há espaços para código HTML, JavaScript e CSS. Isso porque ele é feito apenas para reproduzir exemplos completos nessas linguagens. O site não possui um interpretador PHP integrado, por isso use apenas a formatação de código, botão `{}` do editor.

Comment: Além disso, aconselho a você elaborar um [mcve]. O código que colocou na pergunta parece ser o código completo da página, mas provavelmente muito deste código nem esteja relacionado ao problema.

Comment: Nesse meu caso coloquei o código completo pois qualquer parte dele pode interfere ir no meu problema. exemplo... se eu tirara uma tag qualquer já é motivo pro script funcionar por mais louco que seja isso.. não existe erros no código

Comment: Outro exemplo se eu remover 1 campo do loop ele lista normal. parece algo ligado a memoria

Comment: Cara, divide seu código melhor por trechos..para te ajudar fica melhor